# I have to rewritew composite-id (xml) to JPA

Tags: xml, hibernate, jpa, annotations, composite-id

this is my xml mapping. I need to make JPA mapping

```
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="systemId" type="integer" column="SYSTEM_ID"/>
        <key-property name="rollingRackId" type="integer" column="ROLLING_RACK_ID"/>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="status" type="integer" column="ROLLING_RACK_STATUS"/>
    <property name="changeTime" type="timestamp" column="CHANGE_TIME" />

</class>
```

Comment: and what have you tried? And what problem did you get when you tried something? Or is it that you haven't tried anything and want someone to spend their time to provide you with code?

Comment: I have just started learning hibernate. The only i can try it is research. But unfortunately i did not find needed information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to introduce an Id class

```
@Entity @IdClass(KeyClass.class)
public class Entity{
    @Id int systemId;
    @Id int rollingRackId;

}


class KeyClass{
    int systemId;
    int rollingRackId;
}
```

Comment: how to do it in xml?